# Don't display row the condition is accomplished SQL

Tags: sql

I have :

```
select if(G.grade<5,G.grade,NULL)
```

what condition should I instead of `NULL` to not display the rows?

Comment: Please tag your DBMS and provide sample data with your expected result. It's not clear what you need.

Answer (score 3):

In sql we have a a where statement

```
select -- *
from something
where g.grade<5
```

thisis how you filter rows in sql

---

You're tottaly different question (in the comment) is solved like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN g.grade < 5 THEN g.grade ELSE null END AS badgrade,
       CASE WHEN g.grade >=5 THEN g.grade ELSE null END AS goodgrade
FROM G
```

Comment: I know but I want to make a join like this: *select coalesce(if(G.grade<5,G.grade,NULL)) as BadGrades, coalesce( if(G.grade>=5,G.grade,NULL)) as GoodGrades*

Comment: that isn't a join